# sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError with named tuple in DB model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This is my gist with db model for a user table https://gist.github.com/flamingo0208/d888a2ca03a426a231de172599ec11b4

I am trying to send the following data to update a user record

```
{
"id":164,
"login_id": "abc",
"accountid": "1234",
"project_id": "1",
"status":"Active"
}
```

But I get

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely) (sqlite3.IntegrityError) constraint status_type failed [SQL: 'UPDATE users SET status=?, project_id=? WHERE users.id = ?'] [parameters: ('Inactive', '1', 164)
```

status_type is from named tuple (in gist code).Why am I receiving this error when I am giving valid status field?

Answer (score 0):

you can not put primary key as a update field. so write query like

session.query(Users).filter(User.id == 164).update({"login_id": "abc",
"accountid": "1234",
"project_id": 1,
"status":"Active"
})

Comment: I tried using `{
    "login_id": "abc",
    "accountid": "1234",
    "project_id": "1",
    "status":"Active"
}` but still I get same error. I guess something is wrong with "status" field

Answer (score 0):

ok my users table definition had

```
CONSTRAINT status_type CHECK (status IN ('ACTIVE', 'DISABLED')
```

Because of this constraint check was failing as I was trying to pass "Active" instead of "ACTIVE".